# Ignore parts of script under some circumstances?

Tags: bash, scripting, osx

My script looks like this

```
strenggen ( ) { something; }

strengen 1 
strengen 2
strengen 3
strengen 4
strengen 5
etc..
```

Which adds a few files to the directory called `strengen?string=1`, `strengen?string=2` etc. What I am trying to do is if I quit the script, and the run it again, I want it to find the last number than was run, whether it was 13, 14, 60000 or 140000. Since the file names are contain the last number, I thought I can look for the last modified file and copy that number (e.g `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %N" | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -f2- -d" "` or something similar. If I sed that string I can get the number to start at, but I am not sure how I would ignore the other lines?

Comment: I can't tell if you've simplified this snippet for the sake of your question...but is there some reason you're not using a `for` loop?  `for i in {1..500}; do strengen $i; done`

Answer (score 1):

The following command will put the number of the latest 'strengen' file in the variable `$LATEST`:

```
LATEST=$(/bin/ls -1t | grep `^strengen` | head -1 | sed -e 's/strengen.*=//')
```

I've used `/bin/ls` here rather than just `ls`, in order to eliminate any aliasing that might affect the output of `ls -1` - `ls` is very commonly aliased.

Also note that the `ls` option i'm using is `-1` (number one) not `-l` (letter `l`).  This tells `ls` to list one file per line.  The `-t` option tells `ls` to sort by time, most recent first.

Another alternative would be to put something like the following at the top of your `strenggen()` function:

```
[ -e "strengen?string=$1" ] && return
```

This will cause the function to return immediately without doing anything if the file already exists.

Comment: Nice, but the result was the opposite. I got the oldest edited file.

Comment: It shouldn't have.  check the man page for `ls`: `-t sort by modification time, newest first`.  and it sorted as expected on my system.  you need to use the `-r` option to reverse sorting to get oldest first.

Comment: @cas - you need `ls -tr`.

Comment: @cas, weird mine says something similar too `Sort by time modified (most recently modified first) before sorting the operands by lexicographical order.`

Comment: i just checked it again on several of my systems.  `ls -1t` gives newest first, `ls -1rt` gives oldest first.  as the man page says it will.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. But instead, I get "argument list too long".

Comment: try `ls -1t | grep '^strengen' | head -1 | sed ...`.  i've updated the answer.  it works without the `grep` if there's only a few `strengen*` files, but not if there are thousands...i should have thought of that since you did mention there might be 140,000.

Comment: @cas there is no need for head -1 when piping to sed - simply use `sed -e '1 s/strengen.*=//'`

Comment: my purpose here is to teach the technique.  optimisation comes a very distant second to understanding.